# Can't update user model in express?

Tags: node.js, http, express

I'm trying to do a put request to update a user model but instead my router just sends another get request.

Here's my router

```
router.get('/update', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  res.render('update.ejs', {
      user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
    });
});

router.put('/update', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.body.username;
  var profile_type = req.body.prof_type;
  var pic = req.body.profile_pic;
  var aboutme = req.body.whoami;
  console.log(req.body.whoami);
  User.findById(req.params.id,function(err, userup){
    if (!userup)
      return next(new Error("Couldn't load user"));
    else {
      userup.username = username;
      userup.prof_type = profile_type;
      userup.profile_pic = pic;
      userup.whoami = aboutme;
      userup.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
          console.log('error on update');
        else
          console.log('successful update');
      });
    }
  });
    res.redirect('/profile');

});
```

Here's my html input form

```
<form action="/update" method="put">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <h2> Pick a type of profile</h2>
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="prof_type" value="true">Tutor<br>
                    <input type="radio" class="form-control" name="prof_type" value="false">Student
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Link to profile picture</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="profilepic">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>About me</label>
                    <textarea name="whoami" class="form-control">Enter text here </textarea>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg">Update</button>
            </form>
```

I've also tried changing them to be /update/:username, however, after I click the update button with the fields, I GET this address

```
http://localhost:3000/update?username=bob&prof_type=false&profilepic=bob&whoami=bob
```

Not sure why I'm not updating the model or even why it's not putting. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

HTML only supports `GET` and `POST` requests. See the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-method) for details:

> The method and formmethod content attributes are enumerated attributes
>   with the following keywords and states:
>
> The keyword get, mapping to the state GET, indicating the HTTP GET
>   method. The keyword post, mapping to the state POST, indicating the
>   HTTP POST method. The invalid value default for these attributes is
>   the GET state. The missing value default for the method attribute is
>   also the GET state. (There is no missing value default for the
>   formmethod attribute.)

You can use the `PUT` method only with an ajax request. For example in [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#options):

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/update',
    type: 'PUT',
    success: function(result) {
        // Do something with the result
    }
});
```